# How to put buttons in Angular mat-table?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've sucessfully used Angular mat-table to display data from database:
[image]

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="iccid">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ICCID </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.iccid}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="euicc">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> EUICC </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.euicc}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="msisdn">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> MSISDN </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.msisdn}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status_paket_data">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status paket data </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status_paket_data}}  </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status_sms">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status SMS </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status_sms}}  </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="active_profile">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Active profile </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.active_profile}}  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click) = "rowClicked(row)" ></mat-row>
</mat-table>

<mat-paginator [length]="5" [pageSize]="3" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Now I want to add another column, which contains buttons. So in app.component.ts, I add a new column called **actions**:

```
 displayedColumns = ['iccid', 'euicc', 'msisdn', 'status_paket_data', 'status_sms', 'active_profile', 'actions'];
```

And in app.component.html, I add this before **displayedColumns**:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <mat-header-cell > Actions </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
       <button mat-button >Edit</button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

When the page is refreshed, I get this:

> AppComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template'
>   of undefined
>       at MatHeaderRowDef.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkHeaderRowDef.extractCellTemplate
>   (table.es5.js:280)
>       at table.es5.js:1452
>       at Function.from ()
>       at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable._getCellTemplates
>   (table.es5.js:1447)
>       at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable._renderRow
>   (table.es5.js:1395)
>       at table.es5.js:1289
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable._forceRenderHeaderRows
>   (table.es5.js:1289)

How to properly add column with buttons in it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add the cell column definition `matHeaderCellDef` for the mat header cell

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <button mat-button>Edit</button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But wonder my buttons are simply plain native buttons, not Material Design-themed? I've tested this on Chrome 67 and Edge. This article: https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview shows different result, though.

Comment: Same Issue as anta40 am I missing something?

Comment: Hope you guys included

`import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';`

Comment: Button's Material Design style not applied? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214229/mat-button-style-not-applying-in-dialog-component

Answer (score 18):

This answer helped me a lot. however, I just want to add that in the  `matColumnDef="actions"` you refer to the column **actions**, which should also be included in the component displayedColumns variable.

```
displayedColumns = ['id','name','price'...etc., 'actions']
```

Answer (score 5):

I would like to thank Sachila Ranawaka for his answer. For those using Material 11+, I would only suggest adding the `th` and `td` elements, as they render better looking results (border, padding, elevation, etc).

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef > Actions </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
    <button mat-button >Edit</button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Correct Design Complete Working Answer

I tried all the answers here, some don't work and others work but not properly.

This one got me the results I needed:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef>  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Add this code where the other definitions of `matColumnDef` are located.

The **magic sauce** here is the `*matCellDef` in `td`

Also add to the column array the "actions" column like this:

```
displayedColumns = ['column1', 'column2', 'actions']
```

Answer (score 2):

For earlier version of Angular material below works

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="TableHeaderRow"></th>            
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let myRowData">
      <button mat-fab color="warn" aria-label="Edit Row" (click)="getRecord(myRowData)">
      <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```