# Mat button style not applying in dialog component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have dialog component and I have two mat button inside it but some reason mat-button style is not applying. The button style is working in other components but I'm not sure why it's not applying in just this dialog component.

```
    <button mat-raised-button color = "primary"(click)="onNoClick()" style="margin-left:100px;">No, I'm still working.</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color = "primary"(click)="onNoClick()" style="margin-left:100px;">No, I'm still working.</button>
```

I already imported in both app.module.ts and material.modules.ts file but not sure

app.moudles.ts

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
]
  exports: [MatButtonModule],
```

material.modules.ts

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
}
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
}
```

Any suggestion why it might be?. thank

Comment: where are you declaring your dialog component? In whatever module that is, that module als needs to somehow import the MatButtonModule, either directly or through a shared module

Answer (score 11):

If you using the dialog in a **separate component** and that specific component is **not imported** in your app.module.ts file the **styling will be not applied**.

Most likely after you recreated the component (assuming you used the Angular CLI - ng generate component) the imports were automatically added for you.

Also make sure to stop and reserve the app (ng serve or equivalent) after adding the new import.

Answer (score 1):

I see you do not use the MatDialog. Therefore, I assume the problem relates to material not being fully configured.

Have you set the material theme in the `style.scss` file? 
If you haven't, try adding this line at the top of the `style.scss` file:

```html
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

For further reading, look at this [link](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: thank for the comment. I just create new component, use the exact same code and it work. ha ha. I'm not sure why it don't work on the old component.. lol